# How to check if an appender is disabled/enabled

Tags: c#, logging, log4net

Is it possible to determine if an appender is disabled (i.e. `<level value="Off">`)?

I would like to have a global flag that determines if my appender is enabled:

```
public static bool isAppenderEnabled = /*...*/;
```

If the appender is enabled, then I would log stuff:

```
if(isAppenderEnabled)
{
    MyAppender.Warn("****************************************");
    MyAppender.Warn("Warning title!");
    MyAppender.Warn(String.Format("Some warning message! A:{0}, B:{1}, C:{2}, D:{3}", 0, 1, 2, 3));
    MyAppender.Warn("****************************************");
}
```

It's important to have the `isAppenderEnabled` flag, because I would be saving a lot of CPU time when the appender is disabled due to the fact that I'm not constructing all of those strings. What's the best/easiest way to check if an appender is turned off?

P.S.
I've tried the `MyAppender.Logger.IsEnabledFor(log4net.Core.Level.Off);`, however, if I set the log level to `Warn` it always returns true for `Off` (basically, it always says the logger is disabled), so that doesn't work.

Comment: [may its usefull for you as this is checked answer of simmilar question of yours  ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10126517/1003016

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The recommended way of doing is, isn't to have a global flag to say whether logging is enabled, but rather to test the actual logging level of a per call basis, 
eg

```
if (MyAppender.IsWarnEnabled)
{
    MyAppender.Warn(String.Format("Some warning message! A:{0}, B:{1}, C:{2}, D:{3}", 0, 1, 2, 3));
}
```

...

```
if (MyAppender.IsDebugEnabled)
{
    MyAppender.Debug(String.Format("Some debug info! A:{0}, B:{1}, C:{2}, D:{3}", 0, 1, 2, 3));
}
```

...

```
if (MyAppender.IsErrorsEnabled)
{
    MyAppender.Error(String.Format("Some error message! A:{0}, B:{1}, C:{2}, D:{3}", 0, 1, 2, 3));
}
```

The advantage of this method is that you can set and leave your logging to Level.Error or Level.Fatal without constructing all the strings in your warn/debug and info messages.

Having said that, it is your choice. To answer your question, the reason `MyAppender.Logger.IsEnabledFor(log4net.Core.Level.Off);`
doesn't work, is that MyAppender.Logger.IsEnabledFor(x) will return true if the level is set to x **or higher**. Hence I would expect this call to always return true.

The next level up is (AFAIK)  `log4net.Core.Level.Emergency`  so could check for that, but as that level isn't commonly used,  you could also check for `log4net.Core.Level.Fatal`

`MyAppender.IsFatalEnabled` is just a property wrapper for `MyAppender.Logger.IsEnabledFor(log4net.Core.Level.Fatal)` ,

Answer (score 0):

Based on my understanding of log4j which log4net is based on, you can check if the LOGGER is configured for the level that you are interested in by calling:

```
logger.isEnabledFor(Priority.WARN)  // or whatever log priority you want
```

There isn't anything that tells if an appender is enabled.  You CAN however check to see if a given named appender is assigned to your logger.  You would check:

```
if(logger.getAppender("MyAppender") == null)
```

Comment: I've tried `IsEnabledFor`, but that's limiting and not very robust when we're dealing with multiple log levels.